# Как очистить таблицу mysql?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Всем привет!

Как одним запросом очистить таблицу от всех записей?

Сейчас имею такой код на CI:

Файл **model.php**

```
function clear_log() {
    $this->db->where('event' > '0')->delete("login_history");
}
```

Файл **controler.php**

```
function clear_log() 
    {
        $this->logs_model->clear_log();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('admin currency msg save_success'));
        redirect(site_url("admin/logs"));
    }
```

Файл **view.php**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("admin/logs/clear_log/") ?>" class="btn btn-danger">очистить</a>
```

При выполнении я не получаю каких-либо ошибок, однако записи в БД не удаляются.
Благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для очистки таблицы используйте `truncate()`:

```
$this->db->truncate('login_history');
```

В отличие от `empty_table()`, который генерит `DELETE FROM` SQL запрос, `truncate()` генерирует `TRUNCATE TABLE`, который является более производительным, потому что он удаляет данные путем деаллокации тех страниц, которые хранят табличные данные и только эти операции деаллокации записываются в лог транзакции. `DELETE FROM` в свою очередь удаляет строки в таблице и для каждой оставляет запись в логе транзакции.

Comment: по какой причине этот запрос более производителен, и в каких ситуациях выполнить его не получится?

Comment: @teran `по какой причине этот запрос более производителен` truncate table быстрее тупо by design `в каких ситуациях выполнить его не получится?` нет связи с сервером, неправильное имя таблицы, недостаточно прав, нарушение FK и т.п.

Comment: @Akina мой вопрос был намеком ответчику чем можно улучшить ответ ;) а про не получится выполнить, тут я конечно про ограничения целостности имел в виду.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->empty_table('mytable'); // Produces: DELETE FROM mytable
```

[оф.дока](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data)